# How do I match a private Teams channel to its SharePoint Online site?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working with Microsoft 365 teams, channels and SharePoint Online sites/site collections. I have the Microsoft Graph API and the PnP.SharePoint PowerShell module at my disposal (among other APIs).

Private channels get their own SharePoint sites. I have the following data for the private channel:

```
> Get-PnPTeamsChannel -Team 9e0e388c-ad9e-40c4-a7f5-406060b175af | FL

Type                : 
Tabs                : 
TabResources        : 
Messages            : 
DisplayName         : Private Channel
MembershipType      : private
Description         : 
IsFavoriteByDefault : 
Id                  : 19:2e708ed1ddee425fbcb6f509ea8d497c@thread.tacv2
Members             :
```

I have the following data for the corresponding SharePoint site:

```
> Get-PnPTenantSite https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-PrivateChannel | FL

AllowDownloadingNonWebViewableFiles         : False
AllowEditing                                : True
AllowSelfServiceUpgrade                     : True
AnonymousLinkExpirationInDays               : 0
BlockDownloadLinksFileType                  : WebPreviewableFiles
CommentsOnSitePagesDisabled                 : False
CompatibilityLevel                          : 15
ConditionalAccessPolicy                     : AllowFullAccess
DefaultLinkPermission                       : None
DefaultLinkToExistingAccess                 : False
DefaultSharingLinkType                      : None
DenyAddAndCustomizePages                    : Enabled
Description                                 : 
DisableAppViews                             : NotDisabled
DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks              : NotDisabled
DisableFlows                                : NotDisabled
DisableSharingForNonOwnersStatus            : 
ExternalUserExpirationInDays                : 0
GroupId                                     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
HubSiteId                                   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
InformationSegment                          : 
IsHubSite                                   : False
LastContentModifiedDate                     : 18.01.2022 07:44:15
LimitedAccessFileType                       : WebPreviewableFiles
LocaleId                                    : 1031
LockIssue                                   : 
LockState                                   : Unlock
OverrideTenantAnonymousLinkExpirationPolicy : False
OverrideTenantExternalUserExpirationPolicy  : False
Owner                                       : [REDACTED]
OwnerEmail                                  : [REDACTED]
OwnerLoginName                              : [REDACTED]
OwnerName                                   : [REDACTED]
ProtectionLevelName                         : 
PWAEnabled                                  : Disabled
RelatedGroupId                              : 9e0e388c-ad9e-40c4-a7f5-406060b175af
ResourceQuota                               : 300
ResourceQuotaWarningLevel                   : 200
ResourceUsageAverage                        : 0
ResourceUsageCurrent                        : 0
RestrictedToGeo                             : Unknown
SandboxedCodeActivationCapability           : Disabled
SensitivityLabel                            : 
SharingAllowedDomainList                    : 
SharingBlockedDomainList                    : 
SharingCapability                           : ExternalUserSharingOnly
SharingDomainRestrictionMode                : None
ShowPeoplePickerSuggestionsForGuestUsers    : False
SiteDefinedSharingCapability                : ExternalUserSharingOnly
SocialBarOnSitePagesDisabled                : False
Status                                      : Active
StorageQuota                                : 26214400
StorageQuotaType                            : 
StorageQuotaWarningLevel                    : 25574400
StorageUsageCurrent                         : 0
Template                                    : TEAMCHANNEL#1
Title                                       : Marketing - Private Channel
Url                                         : https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-PrivateChannel
WebsCount                                   : 1
```

I cannot see anything sensible linking these two together.

I have found a way, but don't like it and don't know if it's reliable. I can make the following Graph API call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/9e0e388c-ad9e-40c4-a7f5-406060b175af/channels/19:2e708ed1ddee425fbcb6f509ea8d497c@thread.tacv2/filesFolder

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('9e0e388c-ad9e-40c4-a7f5-406060b175af')/channels('19%3A2e708ed1ddee425fbcb6f509ea8d497c%40thread.tacv2')/filesFolder/$entity",
    "id": "01C2YTDRBXDNT52I3PDBHYAWPR7R5ZFVHC",
    "createdDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-25T14:55:05Z",
    "name": "Private Channel",
    "webUrl": "https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-PrivateChannel/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Private%20Channel",
    "size": 0,
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!oc1UdWZkGke6dY_CL8UCbH68JWN0VxpOmPzYFUC8hoMZ8jgTqQM5S5QHyRVAZnAR",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary"
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2022-01-25T14:55:05Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-25T14:55:05Z"
    },
    "folder": {
        "childCount": 0
    }
}
```

Now I could compare the returned webUrl of the filesFolder with the Url of the SharePoint site ("contains").

Is there another way or a better way? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tenant admin site to get the SharePoint URLs of the private channels. I wrote a description down in https://notdoneyet.blog/powershell/ms%20teams/2022/12/05/Find-private-channels.html

Comment: Your blog post mentions how to get a list of all private channel sites, but not how to get the site of a specific private channel.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're wanting to actually do here, but in simple terms, yes, you could match them up this way. It's not really *actually* necessary to do that though - you can get the SharePoint Online site right from your `filesFolder` call. You have:

`https://redacted.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-PrivateChannel/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Private%20Channel`

That follows a standard pattern:
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/[something, but generally 'sites']/[the site part]/[document library name - note that this is language specific, like in your case it is in German]/[private channel name].

If you remove the last part [document library name/private channel name], you'll be fine. You can use regex or similar to that, grabbing the first part. Another option is to remove https and then split the string on `/` and  grab part '2'.

Comment: Thank you. What I would like to do is to uniquely and unambiguously get the SharePoint site for a private channel. So basically I want the site's internal ID for the channel. Usually I would expect the site to contain the channel ID or the channel to contain the site ID. Comparing URLs is a last resort as those or their structure can change.

Comment: Oh, I see. No, the IDs don't match in that way - as you can see, the site name is derived (in a semi-predictable way) from the Team + Channel name, but you don't need to derive it, you can get it via the API. It doesn't have, for instance, the channel ID, but I think it's better that way - if you're working directly with SharePoint (e.g. PowerShell bulk script) it's easier to see what you're working on. To your concern though, the structure does NOT change post creation. What I mean is, the SharePoint site path stays the same forever, even if you change the channel name later.

Comment: That means you can rely on it staying the same.